# Trouble with using MSBuild API to compile a vcxproj - error MSB4057

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, compilation

I've got a freshly made C++ (`.vcxproj`) project that I've added some files to. Now, I'm attempting to compile it using the following code:

```
var clogger = new ConsoleLogger(LoggerVerbosity.Diagnostic);
var pc = new ProjectCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>{{"Configuration", "Release"},
{"ToolsVersion", "4.0"}},
  new[] { clogger }, ToolsetDefinitionLocations.Registry);
pc.DefaultToolsVersion = "4.0";
pc.LoadProject(projectPath);

var project = new Project(pc);
try
{
  Assert.That(project.Build("Release"), Is.True);
}
finally
{
  pc.UnregisterAllLoggers();
}
```

Unfortunately, attempting to compile the project gives me the following error:

```
Building with tools version "4.0".
MSBUILD : error MSB4057: The target "Rebuild" does not exist in the project.
```

I've tried plenty of targets including not specifying a target at all, and I keep getting the same error. I assume that the `Rebuild` target really is in the project because msbuild from the command line builds it just fine. What am I missing?

Comment: The Rebuild target is defined in C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.BuildSteps.targets

Comment: The project references `Microsoft.Cpp.Targets`... is that enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set your `Project` object as follows:

   ```
      //pc.LoadProject(projectPath); - redundant
      //var project = new Project(pc); - let `ProjectCollection` return your project

      var project = pc.LoadProject(projectPath);
   ```
2. `Build()` takes a [Target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka.aspx) name, not a [Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164288.aspx) name:

So here pass the *Rebuild* target:

```
Assert.That(project.Build("Rebuild"), Is.True);
```